# Sending int through socket in Java

Tags: java, networking, sockets, integer

What is the best possible way to send an int through a socket in Java? Right now I'm looking at

```
sockout.write((byte)( length >> 24 ));
sockout.write((byte)( (length << 8) >> 24 ));
sockout.write((byte)( (length << 16) >> 24 ));
sockout.write((byte)( (length << 24) >> 24 ));
```

and then trying to rebuild the int from bytes on the other side, but it doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, your way should work too, but Adam's answer is better IMO. Though, the regular way of doing this is ((length >> i) & (byte) 0xff) where i is one of (0, 8, 16, 24) which protects you from problems in case the original value of the integer is negative.

Answer (score 29):

Wrap your `OutputStream` with a [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and then just use the `writeInt()` method.

Something else which may be useful is that on the other end you can wrap our `InputStream` in a [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and use `readInt()` to read an `int` back out.

Both classes also contain a number of other useful methods for reading and writing other raw types.

Comment: Only if there's also java of the other end.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy - the other end could be any language.  the DataOutputStream writes almost entirely language agnostic output (except the utf8 strings).

Comment: @jtahlborn Why are utf8 strings an exception? Isn't it all ultimately just bytes anyway?

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy Well, `writeUTF()` uses a format that isn't universal (as opposed to sending an integer, which, other than endianness *is* universal). That's because it sends the length (as a `short`, which is worrying) followed by the UTF-8 bytes. There's nothing wrong or proprietary about *that* format, so you just have to make sure that the other end is expecting that (as opposed to, say, sending the length as an `int` or sending a fixed-size string with no length marker)

Comment: However, DataOutputStream closes wrapped stream when it's closed, which can be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are other type of streams you can use, which can directly send integers. You can use DataOutputStream. Observe,

```
DataOutputStream out;
try {
    //create write stream to send information
    out=new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
} catch (IOException e) { 
    //Bail out
}

out.writeInt(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending small amounts of data, then encoding as character data (e.g. `Integer.toString(length)`) and decoding at the other end is not unreasonable.